# Intellij prefer class.method import

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say I have the following import: `import package1.Interface1;`. `Interface1` is a public interface, and I am using it in my code. Inside `Interface1`, there is another public class called `Class1`.

When I am using `Class1` in my code, the Intellij auto-import imports the class as:

```
import package1.Interface1;


Interface1.Class1();
```

But I would like the auto-import to import `Class1` automatically as:

```
import package1.Interface1.Class1;

Class1();
```

I have been looking through the IntelliJ settings and am not sure which one does that? Would it be some settings under: Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports?

Comment: It should work with 'Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports | Use single class import' checked on. See the full reference here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It is under Editer -> Code Style -> Java -> check `Insert imports for inner classes`.